# Perl TDS character sets

Tags: sql-server, perl, freetds, dbi

I'm using the FreeTDS driver with DBD::Sybase, connecting to an MS SQL Server.  When I query certain values of certain records, I get this error:

```
DBD::Sybase::st fetchrow_arrayref failed: OpenClient message: LAYER = (0) ORIGIN = (0) SEVERITY = (9) NUMBER = (99)
Server , database 
Message String: WARNING! Some character(s) could not be converted into client's character set. Unconverted bytes were changed to question marks ('?').
```

This seems to happen for records that contain special Windows character-set characters, such as curly quotes, copied and pasted from people's Outlook and Word messages.

Unfortunately, I do not have any control of this database; sanitizing the input on the way in is obviously the way to go, but is not available to me.

What FreeTDS settings do I need to change to be able to successfully query these records?

Additional information:

The query works fine from tsql.  I only get this error through Perl's DBD::Sybase interface.  (Should I test through something else?  I don't have the expertise yet to install PHP or Python.  I've got jTDS and can use it, but I think that's a completely different implementation, not an interface to FreeTDS.)

Adding

```
client charset = UTF-8
```

to my freetds.conf file results in "Out of memory!" printed to STDERR.

Comment: Somebody please move this back to StackOverflow.com, since it is a question about Perl programming.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem recently.

In your freetds.conf file you'll want an
entry similar to the following:

```
[DataSourceName]
        host = <IP Address>
        port = <databaseport>
        #version 8.0 seems to work  with sql server 2005
        tds version = 8.0
        client charset = UTF-8
```

client charset is the important bit here.

I was doing this with Perl from Linux, I expect UTF-8 is the best choice here as well, given Perl is the Client

Comment: Cool; that obviously did something.  But now I get this error:
Out of memory!

What in the world is it doing to try that conversion?

Comment: I would be surprised if you are running out of memory doing the actual conversion. I'd look for memory leaks/oversize queries elsewhere first.

Your freetds installation should include a console client program called tsql. Try some queries to see if the problem still lies in freetds.

Comment: The query works fine from tsql.  I don't know enough about FreeTDS to know what is different.

If I write a minimal Perl program that executes just this query, it fails.  The query only gets about 10 records.  I can't imagine that it's running out of memory.  If I get 10 different records, without curly quotes and such, it works just fine.

Comment: Googling around suggests that this is definitely the correct fix.  Maybe I should start another question: "How come I get this out of memory error when I change the client charset?"

Answer (score 2):

Check if this helps ([from Sybase Manuals](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-asarc/srv10024/sag/@Generic__BookTextView/50138;pt=50138#X), but may work on MSSQL server as well):

Controlling Character Conversion During a Session

> set char_convert allows the user to
>   decide how character set conversion
>   operates during a particular work
>   session. Use set char_convert to:
>
> ```
> * Set character set conversion on or off
>
> * Start conversion into a specific character set
>
> * Turn error reporting on or off
> ```
>
> The syntax for set char_convert is:
>
> set char_convert {off |
>                  {on [with {error | no_error}]} | 
>                  charset [with {error | no_error}]}

Comment: Looks like that's only for Sybase.  I get:

DBD::Sybase::st execute failed: Server message number=195 severity=15 state=5 line=1 server=XXX text='char_convert' is not a recognized SET option.

I appreciate it, though.